# Pandas is printing more rows than expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently I work on a database and I try to sort my rows with pandas. I have a column called 'sessionkey' which refers to a session. So each row can be assigned to a session. I tried to seperate the Data into these sessions.

Furthermore there can be duplicated rows. I tried to drop those with the drop_duplicates function from pandas.

```
df = pd.read_csv((path_of_data+'part-00000-9d3e32a7-87f8-4218-bed1-e30855ce6f0c-c000.csv'), keep_default_na=False, engine='python')
tmp = df['sessionkey'].values #I want to split data into different sessions
tmp = np.unique(tmp)


df.set_index('sessionkey', inplace=True)
watching = df.loc[tmp[10]].drop_duplicates(keep='first') #here I pick one example
print(watching.sort_values(by =['eventTimestamp', 'eventClickSequenz']))
print(watching.info())
```

I would have thought that this works fine but when I tried to check my results by printing out my splitted dataframe the output looks very odd to me. For example I printed the length of the Dataframe it says 38 rows x 4 columns. But when I print the same Dataframe there are clearly more than 38 rows and there are still duplicates in it.

I already tried to split the data by using unique indices:

```
comparison = pd.DataFrame()

for index, item in enumerate(df['sessionkey'].values):
    if item==tmp: comparison = comparison.append(df.iloc[index])

comparison.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
print(comparison.sort_values( by = ['eventTimestamp']))
```

But the Problem is still the same.

The output also seems to follow a pattern. Lets say we have 38 entries. Then pandas returns me the first 1-37 entries and then appends the 2-38 entries. So the last one is left out and then the whole list is shifted and printed again.

When I return the numpy values there are just 38 different rows. So is this a problem of the print function from pandas? Is there an error in my code? Does pandas have a problem with not-unique indexes?

EDIT:

Okay I figured out what the problem is. I wanted to look at a long dataframe so I used:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', -1)
```

Now we can use some sample data:

```
data = np.array([[119, 0], [119, 1], [119, 2]])
columns = ['sessionkey', 'event']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columns)
print(df)
```

Printed it now looks like this:

```
    sessionkey  event
0          119      0
1          119      1
1          119      1
2          119      2
```

Although I expected it to look like this:

```
   sessionkey  event
0         119      0
1         119      1
2         119      2
```

I thought my Dataframe has the wrong shape but this is not the case.
So the event in the middle gets printed doubled. Is this a bug or the intendent output?

Comment: Hi, Paul. This problem can't be duplicated by the people who want to help you out. If you can [get the problem to a minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) state then you really increase the chance of someone helping you. Without the data, or a sample, or fake fixture of it, this is very hard to answer.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the original post. The problem should be reduced to its minimal form now.

Answer (score 0):

so `drop_duplicates()` doesn't look at the index when getting rid of rows, instead it looks at the whole row. But it does have a useful `subset` kwarg which allows you to specify which rows to use.

You can try the following

```
df = pd.read_csv((path_of_data+'part-00000-9d3e32a7-87f8-4218-bed1-e30855ce6f0c-c000.csv'), keep_default_na=False, engine='python')

print(df.shape)
print(df["session"].nunique()) # number of unique sessions


df_unique = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["session"],keep='first')

# these two numbers should be the same
print(df_unique.shape)
print(df_unique["session"].nunique())
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to `drop_duplicates` based on the index - by default `drop_duplicates` drops based on the column values. To do that try

`df.loc[~df.index.duplicated()]`

This should only select index values which are *not* duplicated

Comment: No, I'm sorry I did not explain it proberly. The sessionkey can appear more than once. It helps me to split the data into the sessions. A session is made up of more than one row. Each row within a session describes one activity. These activities can be duplicated. So I want to drop those.

Answer (score 0):

I used your sample code.

```
data = np.array([[119, 0], [119, 1], [119, 2]])
columns = ['sessionkey', 'event']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columns)
print(df)
```

And I got your expected outcome.

```
   sessionkey  event
0         119      0
1         119      1
2         119      2
```

After I set the max_rows option, as you did:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', -1)
```

I got the incorrect outcome.

```
    sessionkey  event
0          119      0
1          119      1
1          119      1
2          119      2
```

The problem might be the "-1" setting. The [doc states that "None" will set max rows to unlimited](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html). I am unsure what "-1" will do in a parameter that takes positive integers or None as acceptable values.

Try

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
```